# Which is better method to declare regex pattern?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scrapy, pep8

I have python class file.

```
import re

regex = {
    'a1': re.compile('(\d+)'),
}
# or A1_REGEX = re.compile('(\d+)')

class A1():
    def toview(self, mystring):
        data = regex['a1'].search(mystring)
        if data:
            ......
```

OR

```
import re
class A1():
    a1 = re.compile('(\d+)')
    def toView(self, mystring):
        data = a1.search(mystring)
        if data:
            .......
```

Please anyone tell, which one is better and more accurate. ?
Which one is python standard coding/PEP8 standard ?
In this case, is there any time consumptions or memory usage for regex usage 
can be considered ?
Please add your opinions or comments to this.
Thanks for your valuable comments .!

Comment: mind that in your class methods the first argument always is a reference to the class instance, often called `self`

Answer (score 1):

The second alternative looks much more readable to me, since the class is only referring to itself, not to anything around it. Like in the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Readability counts.

As for performance, there will be no great difference, even if the regular expression increases in complexity. The [regex module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) takes care of caching patterns, so it will be compiled only once:

> The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to `re.match()`, `re.search()` or `re.compile()` are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.

---

#### edit

This would be still nicer:

```
import re

class A1():
   def __init__(self):
       self.preg = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
   def toView(self, mystring):
       data = self.preg.search(mystring)
       if data:
           pass
```

This way, inheritance is much cleaner:

```
class B1(A1):
    def check(self, data):
        return self.preg.match(data)
```

Comment: If base class is extended to some other child class. At that time, is it feasible solution. ?